# Publish to non-existing topic a valid pattern?

Tags: amazon-sns

For my use-case I'm going to have many topics. Because I won't be able to create all topics up-front I would like to create them dynamically. I thought a receiver of an event could create a topic first before subscribing. The sender would simply try to push all the data (the push would fail if nobody created and subscribed for it). Is this a valid pattern?

I know that I have to somehow solve the deletion of topics (the receiver can't do much as others might have subscribed in the meantime as well).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a valid pattern. Actually receiving and processing messages will cost money. If you use SQS recipients, you will need to beware of queue receivers that are not used, though. The costs will add up very quickly.

Depending on your use case, AmazonMQ (SaaS ActiveMQ) may work better. All kinds of Topic policies can be implemented without cost for the listeners or individual topics.

Comment: Can you please point me to cost of unused topics and listeners? I can't find anything...

Comment: My mistake - I had mixed up an old project that used SQS. I've updated my answer.